# How to distinguish processionary from other caterpillars

Tags: zoology, species-identification, entomology

Processionary caterpillars have a vast and harmful presence in southern Europe. In northern Italy, in parks and gardens, I often see caterpillar nests in trees, but I do not know how to tell if they are processionary, with dangerous urticating hair, or other innocous (for humans and pets) kinds of caterpillar (such as tent caterpillar, for example).
I've read from Wikipedia and other sources that processionary "usually" nest in pines and oaks, but it is not clear to me if it is only a matter of preference or if they cannot nest in other trees. Does seeing a caterpillar nest in an another kind of tree safely imply that it is not a processionary nest? 
Besides, the photos I have found show very different kinds of caterpillars,  what easy visual clues could I use to tell them apart? Ideally, I would like to be able from a distance to decide if I should get my dog away from an "infested" tree or if I can safely ignore it.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Bio.SE. Your question could use a bit more context to demonstrate that you've tried answering this on your own. We always ask that the poster provide some evidence of prior research. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to explain a bit more context in an edit. I know nothing of entomology, it is hard for me to find specific sources besides a generic internet search, which has not helped me so far, hence the question.